# why this returning No for all inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select
  filedA,
  conv(filedA, 10, 2),
  case when conv(filedA, 10, 2) like '%1010000'
  or filedA< 31 THEN "NO" ELSE "YES" END AS THEVALUE
from
  table 1
```

The above my sql query always returning Yes value ; which is wrong. For example if the value of field A  80 ,binary value of 1010000 and the return value should be No , but it is returning Yes.

Comment: If the value of filedA is 80 your code returns No.

Comment: The title of this question states the exact opposite of the question. Edit and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

use `and` instead `or`

```
select
  filedA,
  conv(filedA, 10, 2),
  case when conv(filedA, 10, 2) like '%1010000'
  and filedA< 31 THEN "NO" ELSE "YES" END AS THEVALUE
from
  table
```

Comment: that will make the logic incorrect ; even i try it making 'and' still not working

Comment: @GASSAM for 1010000 and 81 this condition is false so it will return yes as 81 is not <31 so it will return yes but if you change filedA>31 then it will return NO

Comment: I got your point the initial logic was to work with or . if the number are less than 30 return 0 else if there is any binary number ending with 1010000 return No else Yes